# Examples for good looking PDF reports

Tags: pdf, reporting, pdf-generation

I am creating PDF reports. I know some basics and try to make them simple. But still, they look ugly. I would like to see some good examples. Are there good looking reports on the web?

I am looking for already created PDFs to look at for inspiration. I am not looking for a report framework.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to write good looking reports you should probably look into LaTEX.

An example report, generated with LaTEX: http://maths.dur.ac.uk/Ug/projects/resources/latex/report/report.pdf

Comment: My reports contain a lot of key-value pairs and tables. Even with LaTeX I need examples to make it look good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, Dynamic Jasper generates good looking reports out of the box

http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have looked at the examples on http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/docs/getting_started.html and those are rather ugly. Are there better ones somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create PDF reports depending on your application platform (desktop application, web application etc) Having done alot of both, the easiest and best ways I have listed below:

**Web Applications** - most essential is HTML-to-PDF creation, where you simply need to point the PDF generator at a URL and it converts it. Simple.

iTextSharp (.NET)(Open Source) - http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp
iText (Java)(Open Source) - http://itextpdf.com/
ABCPDF (.NET) - http://www.websupergoo.com

**Desktop Applications** - an easy interface make life much easier

DataDynamics ActiveReports (.Net) - http://www.datadynamics.com

Comment: This is not the question. I have already chosen a framework for chreating reports. I am looking for good looking report designs.